# scala: Handle tuple where second element of tuple is an array of strings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an rdd and the structure of the RDD is as follows:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] = MappedRDD[40] at map at <console>:14
```

Here is `x.take(1)` looks like:

```
Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((8239427349237423,Array(122641|2|2|1|1421990315711|38|6487985623452037|684|, 1229|2|1|1|1411349089424|87|462966136107937|1568|.....))
```

For each string in the array I want to split by "|" and take the 6th item and return it with the first element of the tuple as follows:

```
8239427349237423-6487985623452037
8239427349237423-4629661361079371
```

I started as follows:

```
  def getValues(lines: Array[String]) {
    for(line <- lines) {
      line.split("|")(6)
    }
```

I also tried following:

```
val b= x.map(a => (a._1, a._2.flatMap(y => y.split("|")(6))))
```

But that ended up giving me following:

```
Array[(String, Array[Char])] = Array((8239427349237423,Array(1, 2, 4, |, 9, |, 4, 1, 7, 6, |, 2, 9, 2, 7, 2, |, 7, |,....)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it for the whole `x` you can use `flatMap`:

```
def getValues(x: Array[(String, Array[String])]) =
  x flatMap (line => line._2 map (line._1 + "-" + _.split("\\|")(6)))
```

Or, maybe a bit more clearly, with for-comprehension:

```
def getValues(x: Array[(String, Array[String])]) = 
  for {
    (fst, snd) <- x
    line <- snd
  } yield fst + "-" + line.split("\\|")(6)
```

You have to call `split` with `"\\|"` argument, because it takes a regular expression and `|` is a special symbol, thus you need to escape it. (**Edit:** or you can use `'|'` (a `Char`), as suggested by @BenReich)

To answer your comment, you can modify `getValues` to take a single element from `x` as an argument:

```
def getValues(item: (String, Array[String])) =
  item._2 map (item._1 + "-" + _.split('|')(6))
```

And then call it with

```
x flatMap getValues
```

Comment: You can also call `split` with `'|'` (the character instead of the string).

Comment: You can also use string interporlation here, which is sometimes clearer:  `x flatMap { case(header, strings) => strings.map(str => s"$header-${str.split('|')(6)}") }`

Comment: @Kolmar when I pass x in to the method I get type mismatch my x is a RDD `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] = MappedRDD[40] at map at <console>:14`

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis So change the type of `x` parameter to `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])]` in the function definition.

Comment: @Kolmar `x.flatMap(y => getValues(y))` ?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis Yes, only for this you'd have to modify `getValues` function as well. Other way is to have `def getValues(x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])])` with the same function body and pass the whole RDD in.

Comment: @Kolmar any chance you could give hint on how to update `getValues` to what I previously type in addition to your original answer. Just want to learn more capabilities of this fascinating language :)

Comment: @Kolmar In addition if I want to add more elements to the output such as `+ _.split("\\|")(6) + _.split("\\|")(5)` why I am i getting error?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis For your second question, look up anonymous function syntax and placeholder syntax in Scala. Each underscore `_` becomes a new function argument. So `line._1 + "-" + _.split('|')(6) + _.split('|')(5)` translates to a function `(t1, t2) => line._1 + "-" + t1.split('|')(6) + t2.split('|')(5)`, but you want only one argument, so in that case you would have to use `t => line._1 + "-" + t.split('|')(6) + t.split('|')(5)` with an explicit argument `t` instead of `_`